# Using jQuery/Ajax to get data from database to apply discount

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm wanting to know the best way to make this form not use a button but return a valid discount code and then apply it to the price and show on page.

```
<input type="text" name="discount_code" value="" class="text" id="discount_code" title="Discount code">
```

This just posts to the same page.

I understand that onChange and Ajax would be used but not sure how to do this, so looking for some help/examples on this please.

Many Thanks.

Comment: The data comes from the database.

Comment: Some help / examples ? [Google is your friend](https://www.google.com/search?q=ajax+example)

Comment: looked on Google first couldn't really find what I need, hence asking here.

Comment: So you need the complete script !! huuh..

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery blur function to call the ajax and communicating with database

**For example**

```
$('#discount_code').blur(function(){
//write your ajax call here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Fully working script, developed last week only, you need to understand the steps, i am not going to explain.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function applyCouponCode() {
    $("#csuc, #cerr").hide();
    $("#csuc, #cerr").html('');
    var coupon = $("#ccode").val();
    if(coupon!='') {
        $("#cload").show();
        $.post('ajax/coupon.php', { coupon: coupon }, function(data) {
            /*optional stuff to do after success */
            switch(data) {
                case 'A':
                    $("#cerr").html('Please enter valid coupon code');
                    $("#cerr").show();
                    $("#cload").hide();
                    break;
                case 'B':
                    $("#cerr").html('You have already used this coupon code');
                    $("#cerr").show();
                    $("#cload").hide();
                case 'C':
                    $("#cerr").html('Please enter a valid coupon code');
                    $("#cerr").show();
                    $("#cload").hide();
                default:
                    var coupon = data;

                    // Now calculate the %age
                    var price = $("#event_subtotal_price").val();
                    var pctge = parseFloat(price) * ( parseFloat(coupon) / 100 );
                    var npric = parseFloat(price) - parseFloat(pctge);

                    pctge = pctge.toFixed('2');  // Total price dicount
                    npric = npric.toFixed('2');  // New price after discount

                    // Display the discount in totalling menu
                    $("#csuc").html('Coupon applied.');
                    $("#csuc").show();
                    $("#cload").hide();
            }
        });
    } else {
        $("#cerr").html('Please enter your coupon code');
        $("#cerr").show();
    }
}
</script>

<div style="margin: 15px 85px;">
    <p>
        Coupon Code <br />
        <span><input type="text" name="ccode" id="ccode" value="" /></span>
        <span id="cbtn"><input type="button" value="Apply" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" onclick="applyCouponCode();"></span>
        <span id="cload" style="display:none;"><img style="margin-bottom: -3px;" src="loader.gif"></span>
        <span id="csuc" style="color:#016B06; display:none;"></span>
        <span id="cerr" style="color:#E40303; display:none;"></span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Coupon.php

```
<?php 

$coupon = $_REQUEST['coupon'];
$user = $_SESSION['picturebooth_customer_id'];

// Get the coupon detail
$coupon_count=$wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `TABLE_COUPON` WHERE `coupan_code` = '$coupon' AND `status`='1'");

if($coupon_count) {

    $result = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM `TABLE_COUPON` WHERE `coupan_code` = '$coupon'");

    $discount = $result->discount;
    $today = strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));
    $from = strtotime($result->from_date);
    $to = strtotime($result->to_date);
    $total = $result->total_number;
    $used = $result->used_number;

    // Checking if the user has already has applied that coupon
    $uc_count = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `USER_COUPON` WHERE `user_id` = '$user' AND `coupon_id`='$result->id'");

    if($uc_count) {
        echo 'B';
    } elseif( $today < $from ) {
        echo 'C';
    } elseif( ($today > $to) || ($used >= $total) ) {
        $wpdb->update('wp_coupons', array( 'status' => '0'), array( 'id' => $result->id ));
        echo 'C';
    } else {
        $wpdb->query("UPDATE `TABLE_COUPON` SET used_number = used_number+1 WHERE `id` = '$result->id'");
        $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO `USER_COUPON` SET `user_id` = '$user', `coupon_id`='$result->id', `date_added` = now()");
        echo $discount;
    }

} else {
    echo 'A';
}
```

Comment: I down voted because it did not edit the price displayed correctly out of the box. I did end up using it on a product. I did have to change it quite a bit, so questions would be reasonable. That is why I down voted it. IF you edit your answer I can up vote it.

Comment: I hope you understand how many version changes are there in 5 years of time. good luck with your code, i accept the downvote :)

Comment: I think a part is missing that actually updates the price. I would remove the down vote but you have to make a change for me to do so because otherwise Stack Overflow will not let me. PS everywhere you have MySQL you could have used Advanced Custom Fields. I.E. using another plugins PHP function to save and edit MySQL data. Makes it a bit easier AND THEN they can update the code from the backend AND if THIS coupon.php is not hidden and the coupon code is in there IF THE HAPPEN TO GO TO IT they could see the discount (as unlikely as that sound) unlike if you use a premade function like with ACF

Comment: But alas, decent example of AJAX implementation that was helpful to me - it just took a bunch of work on my part to make it do anything really...